# Matrix inverse in numpy/python not giving correct matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I have a nxn matrix `C` and use `inv` from `numpy.linalg` to take the inverse to get `Cinverse`. My `C`matrix has elements of order `10**4` but my `Cinverse` matrix has elements of order `10**12` and higher (not sure if thats correct). When I do `numpyp.dot(C,Cinverse)`, I do not get the identity matrix. Why is this?

I have a vector x which I multiply by itself to get a matrix.

```
x=array([ 121.41191662,   74.22830468,   73.23156336,   75.48354975,
     79.89580817])
c=np.outer(xvector,xvector)
```

this is a 5x5 matrix.

then I get its inverse by

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
cinverse=inv(c)
```

then I want to see if I can get identity matrix back.

```
identity=np.dot(C00,C00inv)
```

However, I do not get the identity matrix. cinverse has very large matrix elements
around 10**13 and higher while c has matrix elements around 10,000.

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you show us your input and output? Also, what exactly is the code you are using?

Comment: Could you provide some example code with random matrices to show what you are trying to do? That doesn't sound right- when you say has elements of order 10**4, does that mean that number of elements of that is the size of the number, i.e. 10000ish? Ah, juanpa, beat me to it ;)

Comment: *"I do not get the identity matrix"* - how *close* is it to the identity? You should not expect a matrix of exactly 1s and 0s because of rounding error.

Comment: To be more specific, my matrix elements are of order 10**4. For example, 8000,10000,7000.... etc. I edited original post with some code.

Comment: @RexFuzzle I have edited the original post for clarity. Yes it is for example a 5x5 matrix with the magnitude of the elements being around 10000ish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have added the code and input in the original post

Comment: What's the determinant of your matrix?  How close is it to being singular?

Answer (score 1):

The outer product of two vectors (be they the same or not) is *not* invertible. Since it is just a stack of scaled copies of the same vector its rank is one. Rank defective matrices [cannot be inverted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties).

I'm surprised that numpy is not raising an exception or at least giving a warning.

Comment: Why is this? If you look at eqn 14 of https://academic.oup.com/ptep/article/doi/10.1093/ptep/ptu065/1560725/CMB-foreground-A-concise-review#ref-17 you'll see that I need an outer product of two vectors which creates a covariance matrix (I am just considering l=m=0 case). Eqn 13 requires me to take the inverse

Comment: @NabeelEh But you do get the mathematical argument, I trust? Whatever that paper says. If you have more than one dimension, the outer product is not invertible. That is a fact. Now I really cannot be expected to read your papers for you, but this once: What you have there (14) is _not_ an outer product. It is a _sum_ of outer products. Obviously, if you add enough rank 1 matrices you can get full rank.

Comment: I see. Yes, I get the argument. Thanks Paul, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

So here is some code that generates the inverse matrix, and I will comment about it afterwards.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(5,5)*10000 # makes a 5x5 matrix with elements around 10000
xin = np.linalg.inv(x)
iden = np.dot(x,xinv)
```

Now the first line of your iden matrix probably looks something like this:

`[  1.00000000e+00,  -2.05382445e-16,  -5.61067365e-16, 1.99719718e-15,  -2.12322957e-16]`

. Notice that the first element is exactly 1, as it should be, but there others are not exactly 0, however they are essentially zero and should be regarded as zero according to machine precision.

Comment: Hi @RexFuzzle, I would be happy if those were my results. My vector is x=array([ 4140.56172552,  2561.7498602 ,  2529.56826173,  2607.35090233,
        2759.5614813 ]). I get my matrix by using c=np.outer(x,x) and then inverse using cinv=inv(c). Then using np.dot(c,cinv) my first line is [  6.01898362e-01,   5.53081985e+00,   1.79258876e+00,
         -5.86243807e-01,   1.50883747e+01] which is not identity